# Draw a text completely following a circle

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, drawing

I would like to draw an effect more or less like the following picture: a text is displayed around a circle.

I drew the following picture in Powerpoint by using Shape Format => Transform => Circle as Follow Path over a text. But it is not perfect:

- I would like to inverse the text at the bottom to have a better readability.
- The text can not be connected from end to end.

Does anyone know how to draw it in any software?

[image]